# Available methods to monitor Azure Event hub parititons queue size

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Kafka provides capability to monitor current offset and latest offset. Similarly does azure eventhub expose any api to continously monitor partition's current offset and latest available offset?

Answer (score 2):

Extending above answer, you can see offset by 2 ways.

1. Print offset in log file where you are listening EventHub

e.g using Azure function

```
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("EventHubname", ConsumerGroup = "ConsumerGroupname", Connection = "EventHubConnection")]EventData eventMessage,
        [Inject]IService service, [Inject]ILog log)
    {
    log.Info($"PartitionKey {eventMessage.PartitionKey}, Offset {eventMessage.Offset} and SequenceNumber {eventMessage.SequenceNumber}");
    }
```

2. I am listening Eventhub by Azure Functions, You can see below location where Azure function maintain offset by partition.

[image: From Portal]

**Option 3 (Latest)**

Offset is not the correct way to measure the depth of Eventhub, Specially when you want to check how many messages need to process.

Now We are using Eventhub message SequenceNumber instead Offset. We have created TimerTrigger Azure Function. On every 5 minutes, we are getting **LastEnqueuedSequenceNumber** from Eventhub and **SequenceNumber** for each partition from blob storage (checkpoint location), then we storing difference in ApplicationInsight customMetrics.

Then ApplicationInsights help us to PIN Eventhub depth information in Azure dashboard and set up an alert.

[image: Eventhub Depth in Azure Dashboard]

[Timer Trigger Code](https://github.com/PankajRawat333/EventhubQueueDepthMonitor)

I hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for answering.
Can you describe more about Option 1.
Where can I find logs generated from azure functions?
How can you guarentee offset returned from azure function could be latest offset?
Is is possible to send offsets to remote db in real time?

In Option 2:
In the picture, are you referring to checkpoint information in storage account or is it event hub messages blob?

Comment: @NikeshDevaki I Updated my answer, hope option 3 will help!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Features and terminology in Azure Event Hubs - Event consumers - Stream offsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#stream-offsets):

> An offset is the position of an event within a partition. You can think of an offset as a client-side cursor. The offset is a byte numbering of the event. This offset enables an event consumer (reader) to specify a point in the event stream from which they want to begin reading events. You can specify the offset as a timestamp or as an offset value. **Consumers are responsible for storing their own offset values outside of the Event Hubs service.** Within a partition, each event includes an offset.

And also under *Common consumer tasks - Read events*:

> As events are sent to the client, each event data instance contains important metadata such as the **offset** and sequence number that are used to facilitate checkpointing on the event sequence.

There do not seem to be any methods you can use to monitor the offset since you need to do this yourself.